# MDADM RAID1 creation - What does the initilzation process do?

Tags: mdadm, software-raid

I am creating a RAID 1 mirror pair with MDADM. After creation of the array

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

the array enters an initialization procedure.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

reports progress.

What does this initialization process do? It takes a bit longer than 1 hour so I am assuming the process accesses the entire disk.

Does it mirror binary data from one disk to another? Does it set the binary data on the disk to zero? Or does it do something else entirely?

It isn't really that important it would just be nice to know what it does.

Presumably this is not a procedure which can be skipped?

Answer (score 2):

For RAID 1 the initial sync makes sure there are same data on both legs of the mirror. It's needed because during checks differences would show as errors. You can skip this step using `--assume-clean` but I wouldn't do that unless you are sure the disks contents are the same (e.g. both disks were zeroed).

Detailed information on RAID wiki: https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Initial_Array_Creation

Comment: Interesting. Seems a bit strange to do this rather than just write all zeros to the disks.

Comment: @user3728501 *nix tools tend to leave those decisions to the user: the md driver doesn't know what the drives' content is, it just ensures (in the case of mirroring) that it's the same. If you, for instance, `mdadm --zero-superblock <dev> ...`, effectively destroying an array (but not the data), then you can `mdadm --create ...` using the same drives and get your data back. It's not intended as `mdadm`'s job to assume the given devices don't contain data.

Comment: @fra-san Presumably there is a decision made when the binary data is not the same... For example, does the data get copied from the 0 device of the array to the 1 device? aka: one drive must be a master in a mirror config, with 1 or more slaves?